# How to show ionicPopover by default

Tags: ionic-framework

How to show `ionicPopover` by default, don't click or any other event. Once the page or the view loaded, show the popover?

```
cmr.controller('JoinMeeting', function($scope, $ionicPopover) {
    $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('joinMrTips.html', {
    scope: $scope,
}).then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popover = popover;
});

$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',function(){
    $scope.popover.show();
});

})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were very close. According to the official documentation of IonicPopover, The syntax of popover.show() is as follows :

> **show($event) where  The $event or target element which the popover should align itself next to**

Hence, rewriting your code as follows will do the job :

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',function(){
    $scope.popover.show(".class-of-host-control-of-popup");
});
```

Complete Example, along with code --> [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJtah)

Comment: Glad it helped @user3117414. Please accept my reply as the answer.

Comment: Sadly:Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

Comment: include jquery.js before including angularjs. This is because jqLite by default doesn't allows selection of elements using selectors such as . or #.

Answer (score 2):

This works without having to include jQuery:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',function(){
  $scope.popover.show(angular.element(document.querySelector('.class-of-host-control-of-popup')));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An exemple which uses Ionic "utils" classes (here, DomUtil):

```
    var nodeClass = 'target-host-item-class';
    var evtTarget = $event.target;
    var hostNode = ionic.DomUtil.getParentOrSelfWithClass(evtTarget, nodeClass);

    $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('popover-template.html', {
        scope: $scope
    }).then(function(popover) {
        popover.show(hostNode);
    });
```

Not really worse or better than other answers. Simply avoids using direct DOM queries or jQuery.

Here, I want the popover to always be aligned with the item using the class `.target-host-item-class`.